# Finding values without creating new unifications

Tags: prolog, unification

I have a set of definitions of the form `pair/2` and a predicate `propagate/3`:

```
pair(1, 2).
pair(2, 3).
pair(3, 4).
pair(4, 5).

propagate([], _, []) :- !.

propagate([pair(N, Num)|Tail], Num, [N|ResultTail]) :-
    propagate(Tail, Num, ResultTail), !.

propagate([pair(Num, N)|Tail], Num, [N|ResultTail]) :-
    propagate(Tail, Num, ResultTail), !.

propagate([_|Tail], Num, Result) :-
    propagate(Tail, Num, Result), !.
```

If I have `List = [pair(1, 2), pair(2, 3), pair(3, 4), pair(4, 5)]` and I do

```
propagate(List, 2, Result).
```

I get the desired output, `Result = [1, 3]`; i.e. the list of all numbers that form a pair with `2`.

However, if I have `List = [pair(N1, N2), pair(N2, N3), pair(N3, N4), pair(N4, N5)]` and if I do

```
propagate(List, N2, Result)
```

then the output is

```
N2 = N3, N3 = N4, N4 = N5,
Result = [N1, N5, N5, N5].
```

I would like the output to be `Result = [N1, N3]`, instead. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

([==](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28==%29/2))/2 does the trick

```
propagate([], _, []) :- !.

propagate([pair(N, X)|Tail], Num, [N|ResultTail]) :-
    X == Num,
    propagate(Tail, Num, ResultTail), !.

propagate([pair(X, N)|Tail], Num, [N|ResultTail]) :-
    X == Num,
    propagate(Tail, Num, ResultTail), !.

propagate([_|Tail], Num, Result) :-
    propagate(Tail, Num, Result), !.
```

yields

```
?- List = [pair(N1, N2), pair(N2, N3), pair(N3, N4), pair(N4, N5)], propagate(List,N2,Result).
List = [pair(N1, N2), pair(N2, N3), pair(N3, N4), pair(N4, N5)],
Result = [N1, N3].
```

Note that facts pair/2 don't play any role in your program, and that you should query a variable shared (I used `N2` instead of `P2`).

Also, why all those cuts at rules' end ? Useless cuts are often dangerous.

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. I meant `N2`, not `P2`. I used to cuts because I want it to stop when it finds just one match. I don't really know how to use Prolog, so I might have very well done something useless.

Comment: 'I want it to stop when it finds just one match' it's the intended use, ok, but then place where there is something to cut: `propagate([pair(N, X)|Tail], Num, [N|ResultTail]) :-
    X == Num, !,
    propagate(Tail, Num, ResultTail).`